# Angular universal ng generate universal --clientProject

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-universal, angular-cli-v6

After typing :

```
ng g universal --clientProject project-name
```

i get this:

```
Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 3389
```

i which file i should look for an error? I know what this error mean but don't know how to find the right place to fix this.

Comment: now i get something else: Cannot find BrowserModule import in /src/app/app.module.ts